Prove in an acute angled triangle $ABC$ that: $\min \left\{ \frac{|KD|}{|AD|}, \frac{|LE|}{|BE|}, \frac{|MF|}{|CF|} \right\} \leq \frac{1}{3}.$

PROBLEM: Let us consider an acute-angled triangle $ABC$. Let $D$, $E$, $F$ be the feet of the altitudes from the vertices $A$, $B$, $C$, respectively. Furthermore, let $K$, $L$, $M$ denote the points of intersection of the lines $AD$, $BE$, $CF$ with the circumcircle of the triangle $ABC$ different from the vertices $A$, $B$, $C$, respectively. Prove that the following inequality holds: $$ \min
\left\{ \frac{|KD|}{|AD|}, \frac{|LE|}{|BE|}, \frac{|MF|}{|CF|} \right\} \leq \frac{1}{3}. $$

I have tried it in this way:
We know that, $KD$ = $DO$, where $O$ is the orthocenter of triangle $ABC$
And, $OD = 2R\cdot \cos A$ and $AO = 2R\cdot \cos B \cos C$ and $AD = 2R\cdot \sin B \sin C$.
WLOG, if we let $\dfrac{KD}{AD}$ to be minimum and $\dfrac{CF}{FM}$ to be maximum, then:
$$\frac{\cos A}{\sin B \sin C} \leq \frac{\cos B}{\sin A \sin C} \leq \frac{\cos C}{\sin A \sin B}.$$
From that we get
$$\sin 2A \leq \sin 2B \leq \sin 2C$$
or, $C \leq B \leq A$.
Thus, $c \leq b \leq a$.
Now, assuming the last statement, we now have to prove that
$$\frac{KD}{AD} \leq \frac{1}{3},$$
which, essentially, means, $2 \ OD \leq AO$.
Now, $$\frac{AO}{OD} = \frac{2R \cos A}{2R \cos B \cos C}.$$
Invoking cosine rule, we get:
$$\frac{AO}{OD}= 2 \cdot \frac{\mathbb (a^2)\cdot(b^2+c^2-a^2)}{(a^2+b^2-c^2)\cdot(c^2+a^2-b^2)}.$$
I can't proceed further from this. Can anyone please give some hints about how to proceed from this, or suggest some better ways to solve the problem?
Any help will be appreciated.

I think power of a point theorem will be helpful here

First of all, you could notice that for a right rectangle in $A$, both $\vert LE\vert$ and $\vert MF\vert$ are $0$, so the inequality is trivialy verified. Next for an equilateral triangle, we have $\frac{|KD|}{|AD|} = \frac{|LE|}{|BE}= \frac{|MF|}{|CF|}= \frac{1}{3}$. You should then be able to show that for the more acute of the angles the quotient is less than $\frac 1 3$

WLOG, assume $$\frac{KD}{AD}\le\frac{LE}{BE}\le\frac{MF}{CF}$$
Since $KD=HD=2R\cos B\cos C$ and $AD=2R\sin B\sin C$, we have
$$\frac{2R\cos B\cos C}{2R\sin B\sin C}\le\frac{2R\cos C\cos A}{2R\sin C\sin A}\le\frac{2R\cos A\cos B}{2R\sin A\sin B}$$
$$\cot B\cot C\le\cot C\cot A\le\cot A\cot B$$
Also, since
$$\cot B\cot C+\cot C\cot A+\cot A\cot B=1$$
$$\cot B\cot C+\cot B\cot C+\cot B\cot C\le1$$
$$\cot B\cot C\le\frac{1}{3}$$
Therefore,
$$\min
\left\{\frac{KD}{AD},\frac{LE}{BE},\frac{MF}{CF}\right\}\le\frac{1}{3}$$

Oh! My bad, I have actually switched the formula for $AO$ and $OD$ in my solution...sorry for my mistake. Anyway, thanks for the solution very much!
